# input field to put javascript/json and security issues

Tags: javascript, security, json

I want to let visitors of my web pages to access a textarea where they can write a tiny bit of javascript to configure certain features.

Imagine the javascript to be something like this:

{
   max:100;
   allowFeedback:false;
   filterEnabled:true ;
}

I would want to eval what they write and then my javascript would do something depending on your choices:

so this would be:

var userCode = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
   var result = eval(userCode);
   ..
   if (result.filterEnabled) { ... }
   if (result.allowFeedback) { ... } 
   ...

The question is: 
the user could really type any javascript in there ? 
something malicious, something wrong
what can I do to validate its code before executing ?

Many thanks

Comment: +1 great question that few people can answer correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Read this article about JSON and security. Code and example are also present there - [Parse JSON using JSON Parser or eval()!](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2008/10/parse-json-using-json-parser-or-not.html) . That should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you `eval` what they write, they could indeed write and run any javascript that you could write at the place of the `eval` call. I would suggest only allowing a very limited syntax (e.g. `variable=value`, with a limited set of allowed variables and values), and then parse that.

Edit: If available, you could also use a JSON parser for JavaScript instead of `eval`, e.g. `JSON.parse`.

Comment: how do I allow a very limited syntax ?

Comment: Write a small parser in JavaScript that only recognises e.g. `variable=value` pairs and only the variables you define, and checks the values before assigning them to the variables. No `eval`. Or use regexps to remove everything even potentially dangerous (all special characters, etc) before `eval` - better specify a very limited set of what to allow rather than try to anticipate every possible “bad” input separately.

Comment: (Or you can use `JSON.parse` or similar, if available, to parse the JSON subset of JavaScript. Just don't `eval` arbitrary input.)

Answer (score 0):

Read this [on CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) ... not a good idea to eval any user input, trust me.

Comment: is there anything I can do before evaling

Comment: Remove every "dangerous" character ... just like Arkku said, you have to limit the freedom of the user to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is vulnerable to [DOM Based XSS](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) and all of the rules for exploiting XSS still apply.   Its not often that vulnerabilities can be found in JavaScript,  but this is a good case of it.   I would avoid using this code.  If you **really** want this feature then you should put it on its own domain which doesn't have sessions/authentication/anything of value.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar kind of usecase long ago. This may seems childish answer but before evaluating you can parse the characters like < > and . specially. SO that the content will no longer be a valid program. Mainly the scripting contains dots and < > and that can be filtered for the evaluation. or replaced by some other characters.